# Using arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis to only return 'Join_Count'

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join

I want to join 2 shapefiles, and receive a new output feature that only contains the count in the joins.

I know to use `arcpy.FieldMappings()` to set what fields map from the target and join features, and by default a `Join_Count` field is added to the output feature.

If I supplied an empty `arcpy.FieldMappings()` object to the `SpatialJoin_analysis()` function parameter, would I be able to just do a join and only get the `Join_Count` field?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this is useful. You already have a built-in function that returns what you need. Why not just ignore the extra columns?

Comment: @BrianW. How do you mean? The `SpatialJoin_analysis()` will in fact return a new column (`Join_Count`) but the resulting output feature will also have all the columns from the target and join features. I want the tool to ignore them entirely and not waste time mapping them at all.

Comment: @BrianW. If I am not mistaken, the `SpatialJoin_analysis()` tool is the tool I would use to replicate right-clicking on a target layer and selecting `Join and Relate... > Join... > Join Data Dialog` right?

Comment: The help does say this is the default behavior and to use Field Mappings to control what fields are brought over. I would suggest trying to create an empty Field Mapping object, and see if it does what you want. If the tool gives you an error, then you probably can't do that. In that case, try supplying just one field from the target features layer and letting it process. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm

Comment: @dslamb That is my plan (unfortunately busy doing a plethora of other things). I wish there was a tool that replicated the `Join Data Dialog` functionality, but as [documented](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/essentials-of-joining-tables.htm), there isnt and I just want that `Count_`.